# PHP ReflectionFunction getDefaultValue error

Tags: php, function, reflection

Tengo el siguiente pedazo de código que busca los parámetros y valores por defecto de las funciones indicadas sin embargo da error y he leído y probado alternativas y no lo consigo.

```
foreach($funciones['declaraciones'] as $funcion => $archivo) {
    $funcionRf = new ReflectionFunction($funcion);
    foreach($funcionRf->getParameters() as $indice => $parametro) {
//        $default = "";
//        if ($parametro->isOptional()) $default = $parametro->getDefaultValue(); <-- ERROR
//        if ($parametro->isDefaultValueAvailable()) $default = $parametro->getDefaultValue(); <-- ERROR
//        $funciones['parametros'][$funcion][$parametro->getName()] = $default;

        $funciones['parametros'][$funcion][$parametro->getName()] = $parametro->getDefaultValue(); // <-- ERROR
    }
}
```

`$funciones['declaraciones']` es un array válido. Los nombres (`$parametro->getName()`) los obtiene correctamente. Por qué los valores por defecto no?

Estoy usando PHP7.0.33.

Graceas!

Comment: Intenta verificar que el parámetro sea realmente opcional, algo como `if ($parametro->isOptional())`

Comment: @Josbert lo probé, de hecho está comentado en el código como una de las cosas que probé.

Comment: Puedes incluir el contenido de ````$funciones````

Comment: @SoyCésarMora ya descubrí el error. Lo estoy depurando y vuelvo con las observaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueeno.. con un `try.. catch` y un  `defined()` conseguí resolver el problema.

Contexto: el `foreach` procesa un array secuencial con los nombres de las funciones a analizar: obtener parámetros y sus valores por defecto.

Problema (en mi caso): para obtener TODAS las funciones leo todos los archivos y me traigo las definiciones así no se me escapa ninguna función.  En algunos archivos puedo definir alguna función específica para un script standalone (como lo llamo yo) y en otros casos hay funciones de JS. Esas funciones standalone y las de otros lenguajes nunca van a poder ser procesadas con `ReflectionFunction` porque no están definidas en ese momento.

Solución: puse un `try.. catch` dentro del primer `foreach` y cada función que no se puede procesar se guarda en una clave diferente del array de salida y queda a criterio del programador qué hacer. La info ahí está y ese es el objetivo.

Así que este es el código resultante:

```
foreach($funciones['declaraciones'] as $funcion => $archivo) {
    try {
        $funcionRf = new ReflectionFunction($funcion);
        foreach($funcionRf->getParameters() as $indice => $parametro) {
            $default = "";
            if ($parametro->isOptional()) $default = $parametro->getDefaultValue();
//        if ($parametro->isDefaultValueAvailable()) $default = $parametro->getDefaultValue(); // <-- ERROR. Cuándo usaría esto?
            $funciones['parametros'][$funcion][$parametro->getName()] = $default;
        }
    } catch(ReflectionException $e) {
        if (!defined($funcion)) { // la función no está definida. Hay un par de posibilidades:
                                // puede ser una función específica que esté definida en un archivo que no se
                                // incluyó (include/require,
                                // aunque puede haber sido obtenido de la lista de archivos) (mi caso. metí esa función
                                // en el archivo de funciones y lesto)
                                // o que sea una función de otro lenguaje (que tmb tng ese caso)
                                // TO-DO: identificar si la función no definida es para PHP o para otro infame lenguaje
                                // en caso de que sea para PHP procesarla

            $funciones['??'][$funcion] = $archivo;
        }
    }

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($funciones);echo"</pre>";
```

Fin.